# kendo grid date format datasource

Tags: date, kendo-ui, grid, datasource

I have a kendo grid with a date column. In order to format the date, I'm using:
format: `{0: dd/MM/yyyy }`.

All is well, until I try updating the data source of the grid:

```
                    chargesDS.data(ko.toJS(newValue));
                    chargesDS.sync();
                    chargesGrid.refresh();
```

the .data() call (first line) breaks the date column, causing the format to go back to some default format.

Is there a way to refresh the grid so that the dates are displayed properly again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who ends up here: I got around the problem by using a template:

```
function KendoDateTemplate (dateFormat, propertyName) {
    var temp =
        "#= " + propertyName + " ?" + //is the date non-null? if yes, parse. If no, show empty string. 
        "kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(moment(" + propertyName + ").toDate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), '" + dateFormat + "' ) " +
        " : \"\" #"; //second half of tertiary exp

    return temp;
};
```

...and in the grid options:

```
{
    field: "DateField", title: "Date",
    template: KendoDateTemplate('MM/dd/yyyy', 'DateField')
}, ...
```